# Increase font size with jquery

Tags: jquery, input, optimizely

I'm attempting to run a split test with Optimizely and need to increase the size  of the font that is used as description text in my site search's search field.

I've managed to change the color using this code:

```
$("input[value]").css({"color":"#cc0000"});
```

But if I add on font-size to this nothing happens? 
i.e.

```
$("input[value]").css({"color":"#cc0000", "font-size" : "1.9rem"});
```

I've also tried the following but it still doesn't seem to work??

```
$("input").css({"font-size" : "1.9rem"});
```

Comment: works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z9f0b8y6/)

Comment: did you try inspecting to see if there is some rule sets a `font-size` as `!important` ?

Comment: This works just fine. May be your browser doesn't support `rem` unit. Which browser you're using?

Comment: @Bhojendra Nepal Hmm weird, I'm using Google Chrome browser.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Yes there is an !important statement in the .css file. But I've tried adding this to my jquery and it doesn't work?

Comment: I posted one answer. take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have `!important` over riding the changes made using `.css()` function. So do the following.

```
$("input")
    .css({
        'cssText':'font-size:1.9rem !important',
        'color':'#cc0000'
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/d4wzk4kz/1/)

Comment: Thank you, this worked, however it did overwrite my font color change?

Comment: I just reorder the code so the color change comes next and this sorted it.

Comment: @bbacarat http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/d4wzk4kz/1/ I've made changes to the fiddle. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Try do it like this:

```
var fontSize = parseInt($("input").css("font-size"));
fontSize = fontSize + 1 + "px";
$("input").css({'font-size':fontSize});
```

or

```
var fontSize = $('input').css('font-size').split('px')[0];

var fontInt = parseInt(fontSize) + 1;

fontSize = fontInt + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

I have provided a jsFiddle which will hopefully be the answer you are looking for

https://jsfiddle.net/07x2trL9/1/

Html

```
<input style="font-size:15px" class="big-font" type="text" />
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('.big-font').css("font-size", "25px");
});
```

You simply target your input and change the size like so

Answer (score 0):

Is this just a typo? try

```
$("input").css({"font-size" : "1.9em"});
```

'em' instead of 'rem'

Comment: @Colm Ryan, thanks for replying but this didn't change anything.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood the question, I set up a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/gajy3x3k/1/ and I definitely see the text size change. Also I was completely wrong about 'rem', though it may not work with all browsers.